# Why is this Reference Error appearing? (Cordova plugin, Facebook, Javascript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, cordova, firebase

I'm trying to integrate a "Log in with Facebook" option into my Cordova app. I'm writing in HTML, CSS and Javascript, and wish to deploy the finished app to Android and iOS. I'm currently testing on my Android phone and while my app was working correctly, it began to show this error when trying to integrate the Facebook login:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: CordovaFacebook is not defined`

I'm also integrating Firebase into my app - I'm using their sample chat application code here: https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d (I've replaced my Firebase values in the below code with dummy values).

I'm using the `cordova-plugin-facebook 0.2.2 "CordovaFacebook"` plugin (https://github.com/bisrael/cordova-plugin-facebook). This is my current HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<title>ZeroToApp</title>
<style>
  #messages { width: 40em; border: 1px solid grey; min-height: 20em; }
  #messages img { max-width: 240px; max-height: 160px; display: block; }
  #header { position: fixed; top: 0; background-color: white; }
  .push { margin-bottom: 2em; }
  @keyframes yellow-fade { 0% {background: #f2f2b8;} 100% {background: none;} }
  .highlight { -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1; animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1; }
</style>
<script>

// Issue seems to be CordovaFacebook isn't defined? but it does exist in the correct subfolder... maybe it's not initialized correctly?

function logInWithFacebook(){
    CordovaFacebook.login({
   permissions: ['email', 'user_likes'],
   onSuccess: function(result) {
      if(result.declined.length > 0) {
         alert("The User declined something!");
      }
      /* ... */
   },
   onFailure: function(result) {
      if(result.cancelled) {
         alert("The user doesn't like my app");
      } else if(result.error) {
         alert("There was an error:" + result.errorLocalized);
      }
   }
});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Step 0: HTML defined, variables for elements
  var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages'),
      textInput = document.getElementById('text'),
      sendButton = document.getElementById('send'),
      login = document.getElementById('login'),
      googleLogin = document.getElementById('google'),
      facebookLogin = document.getElementById('facebook'),
      signedIn = document.getElementById('loggedin'),
      logout = document.getElementById('logout'),
      usernameElm = document.getElementById('username'),
      password = document.getElementById('password'),
      username = "Web";

  var config = {
    apiKey: "MyapiKey",
 //   authDomain: "MyauthDomain",
    databaseURL: "MydatabaseURL",
    storageBucket: "MystorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789"
  };

  // Get the Firebase app and all primitives we'll use
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config),
      database = app.database(),
      auth = app.auth(),
      storage = app.storage();

  var databaseRef = database.ref().child('chat');
  sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var chat = { name: username, message: textInput.value };
    databaseRef.push().set(chat);
    textInput.value = '';
  });
  // Listen for when child nodes get added to the collection
  databaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    // Get the chat message from the snapshot and add it to the UI
    var chat = snapshot.val();
    addMessage(chat);
  });

  // Show a popup when the user asks to sign in with Google
  googleLogin.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  });
  // Allow the user to sign out
  logout.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    auth.signOut();
  });
  // When the user signs in or out, update the username we keep for them
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      setUsername(user.displayName);
    }
    else {
      // User signed out, set a default username
      setUsername("Web");
    }
  });

  function handleFileSelect(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    // Get a reference to the location where we'll store our photos
    var storageRef = storage.ref().child('chat_photos');

    // Get a reference to store file at photos/<FILENAME>.jpg
    var photoRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
    var uploadTask = photoRef.put(file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, null, function() {
      // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
      var downloadUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
      textInput.value = downloadUrl;
    });
  }
  file.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  function setUsername(newUsername) {
    if (newUsername == null) {
        newUsername = "Web";
    }
    console.log(newUsername);
    username = newUsername;
    var isLoggedIn = username != 'Web';
    usernameElm.innerText = newUsername;
    logout.style.display = isLoggedIn ? '' : 'none';
    facebookLogin.style.display = isLoggedIn ? 'none' : '';
    googleLogin.style.display = isLoggedIn ? 'none' : '';
  }
  function addMessage(chat) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var nameElm = document.createElement('h4');
    nameElm.innerText = chat.name;
    li.appendChild(nameElm);
    li.className = 'highlight';
    if ( chat.message.indexOf("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/") == 0
      || chat.message.indexOf("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/") == 0
      || chat.message.indexOf("http://pbs.twimg.com/") == 0
      || chat.message.indexOf("data:image/") == 0) {
      var imgElm = document.createElement("img");
      imgElm.src = chat.message;
      li.appendChild(imgElm);
    }
    else {
      var messageElm = document.createElement("span");
      messageElm.innerText = chat.message;
      li.appendChild(messageElm);
    }
    messagesList.appendChild(li);
    li.scrollIntoView(false);
    sendButton.scrollIntoView(false);
  }
  //window.app = app; // NOTE: just for debugging
  //for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) addMessage({ name: "Web", message: ''+i });
  setUsername('Web');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <div id='header'>
    <label for='username'><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/account_box_black_24dp.png" width="24"/></label>
    <span id='username'></span>
    <span id='login'>
      <button id='google' class='idp-button'>Sign in with Google</button>
      <button id='facebook' class='idp-button'>Sign in with Facebook</button>
    </span>
    <button id='logout' class='idp-button'>Sign out</button>
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
  <ul id='messages'></ul>
  <div id='footer'>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/add_a_photo_black_24dp.png" width="24" onClick="logInWithFacebook();"/>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input id='text'></input>
    <button id='send'>Send</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**

- I have logInWithFacebook(); set to run on click of an image for testing purposes.
- I've commented out the "authDomain" value as I was receiving an error, this answer suggested commenting it out so that's what I've done: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/eUzTjj8mVa4
- At first I thought the error was due to the .js file containing FacebookCordova not being included between the head tags, but this isn't correct, as `FacebookCordova`is defined in `[projectname]\plugins\cordova-plugin-facebook\www\CordovaFacebook.js` so it is included in the app.
- I correctly defined my Facebook App Name and Id when I installed the plugin via node.js.
- I've included a div with id="fb-root" in the body of my HTML for Facebook functionality.

I'm really confused as to why this error is happening, I just want to integrate a "Log in with Facebook" option and retrieve a key so that I can authenticate the user into Firebase.

Any help or advice with this would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Update**
This is my current .xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.myhelloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#009900" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/starsplash.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook" >
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="MYAPPID" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="MYAPPNAME" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that your code includes `cordova.js`. Your HTML file should have the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Without that, the Cordova web/native bridge can't initialize, and the plugins won't work either.

Comment: Hi @kerri-shotts thanks for your answer, I thought that might be it, but I've already tried that method. According to this answer (for a different but similar Cordova plugin): https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/98 the .js file doesn't need to be included separately, it's already included in the build as it exists in ``[projectname]\plugins\cordova-plugin-facebook\www\CordovaFacebook.js``I've opened the file, and CordovaFacebook is defined correctly inside it.

Comment: Hi again @kerri-shotts I've tried including the .js file directly by linking to the raw github file. It seems to have found the file, but it's now showing the following error: ``Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined`` it points to this line in CordovaFacebook.js: ``var exec = function() { cordova.exec.apply(cordova, arguments); }`` Is there something I'm missing, I can't see where "cordova" is defined, do I need to include an xml or json file too or something similar? The plugin docs weren't clear: https://github.com/bisrael/cordova-plugin-facebook Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: This is the .js file in question: https://github.com/bisrael/cordova-plugin-facebook/blob/master/www/CordovaFacebook.js line 12 is where the above error is appearing.

Comment: Don't link to the plugin's javascript file  -- Cordova will take care of that for you if you've added the plugin to your project (or config.xml).

However, you must, absolutely, source "cordova.js" in your index.html file. It won't be present in your project's "www" directory, but Cordova adds the file for you. Cordova does _not_, however add the script tag to your file for you -- you have to do that yourself.

It might help to see your config.xml (minus identifying/secret information). It would also help to know how you're building the app (CLI, PhoneGap Build, using the Developer app...)

Comment: Hi again, I've added the xml file to the end of my question. I've also removed the direct link to the javascript in my index.html file, and have included cordova.js. I'm using node.js to add plugins and to build/launch the app onto my Android device. I'm writing the code in Notepad++ and viewing console log errors by accessing the phone through my laptop's Chrome browser. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the error message still the same? Also, update your index.html file. That way I can easily copy & paste what you have into a test project and see what I get.

Comment: Hi Kerri, I've updated my question with my current index page. It appears to be functional now :) however there's now an issue with Facebook. The plugin seems to run correctly (a loading circle appears and it attempts to log in, but then I receive the following error: http://imgur.com/gallery/LBgST ) I think this is outside the scope of this question, so I will mark yours as the correct answer, but do you have any idea why I'm seeing this error? I've read that it might be due to my app not being added on the Android platform in Facebook developer settings, I didn't think I'd need to do...

Comment: ...that as it's a Cordova app, not a native one. But I've tried to add Android as a platform on there just now and it's asking me for things I don't have (such as "Package Name" and "Default Activity Class Name") but I don't have these as I'm developing a Cordova App, not a native Android one. :(

Comment: I'm not sure on that point. I see you've already commented on an issue on the plugin's repo, which is where I would have redirected you as well. Hopefully you get a good answer there. :-)